# VBA - auto-populate date when data entered in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a tracking spreadsheet where I'd like the date a cell is completed to auto-populate in the next column.  I found the following code which works for the first (I:I), but I'd like to add the same code to 5 other columns (i.e. when data is entered in K1, date populates in L1, when data is entered in P1, date populates in Q1).

I've never used VBA before.  I tried just copying/pasting the code and changing the Range, but I get an Ambiguous Name error.  How do I change the name so that I can reuse the code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("I:I")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Melanie

Answer (score 2):

The change to incorporate multiple columns is quite simple.  Only one line of code needs to be changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("I:I,K:K,P:P")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This will monitor columns **I**, **K**, and **P**